# ActiveSheet in Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am not sure if I am even trying this with the right approach. I have a Template worksheet from where I am copying cells to another Worksheets. On each Worksheet where I am copying is "helper" cell to identify Worksheet (1, 2, 3, 4). I would like to refer to different cells on third worksheet and based on value create an IF statement.

This formula is on Template Worksheet:

```
=IF(C462="";"";IF(IF(C1=1;OtherData!$M$24;IF(C1=2;OtherData!$M$104;IF(C1=3;OtherData!$M$105;IF(C1=4;OtherData!$M$106))))="Fixed price";0%;30%))
```

I am copying it to Sheet "Calculation 1" where value in C1 is 1. As a result after Copy - Paste operation it looks like (on Worksheet Calculation 1):

```
=IF(C55="";"";IF(IF(#REF!=1;OtherData!$M$24;IF(#REF!=2;OtherData!$M$104;IF(#REF!=3;OtherData!$M$105;IF(#REF!=4;OtherData!$M$106))))="Fixed price";0%;30%))
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Other options are also welcomed!

Comment: Would you like to replace `#REF` with `C1`? If yes, use absolute reference in the template Worksheet: `$C$1=2` instead of `C1=2`. otherwise, Excel tries incrementing (decrementing, in fact, in your example) and it cannot decrease the row reference with 411 rows... Of course, you must proceed in the same way with `C1=3, C1=3 `,  too...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, preferably by some clever formula. I am also not sure if this nested IF formula is any good in terms of performance. If I have 100 of them on one worksheet.

Comment: In order to come with other options we must know what you want accomplishing... I just tried helping in keeping the lost reference...

Comment: You can add it as an answer. I can ask another question as you have solved my problem for what has been asked in this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to replace `#REF` with C1, please, use absolute reference in the template Worksheet: `$C$1=2` instead of `C1=2`.

Otherwise, Excel tries incrementing (decrementing, in fact, in your example) and it cannot decrease the row reference with 411 rows... Of course, you must proceed in the same way with `C1=1, C1=3` , too...